# How can I use an icon for a label in a Vuetify select dropdown?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm pretty new to Vue/Vuetify. I'm working on select option for a site I'm working on, and I want to use an icon as the label as opposed to text. I want to do something like the image below, but I'm not sure if it's even possible. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**HTML**

```
    <div id="app">
  <v-app class="container">
    <v-select
      v-model="select"
      :items="permissions"
      label="Select"
      item-text="name"
    >
      <template v-slot:item="slotProps" >
        <i :class="['mr-2', 'mdi', slotProps.item.flag]"></i>
        {{slotProps.item.name}}
      </template>
     </v-select>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**VUEJS**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    select: null,
    permissions: [
      {
        name: "Global",
        flag: "mdi-earth"
      },
      {
        name: "Private",
        flag: "mdi-lock"
      }
   ],
  }
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use vuetify selection slot for `v-select` and show the icon of the selected item instead of test.
something like this:

```html
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-select
      v-model="value"
      :items="items"
      label="Select Item"
      multiple
    >
      <template #selection="{ item }">
        <v-icon> {{ getItemIcon(item) }} </v-icon>
      </template>
    </v-select>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

and you need to write the `getItemIcon` method as to return the icon based on the text.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my side it does not work as I wanted - the icon to be inside the selection text and when selected, to show it. Therefore, I added another template as follows:

```js
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-select
      v-model="value"
      :items="items"
      label="Select Item"
    >
      <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
        <v-icon> {{ getItemIcon(item) }} </v-icon>
      </template>

      <template #selection="{ item }">
        <v-icon> {{ getItemIcon(item) }} </v-icon>
      </template>
    </v-select>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

If someone knows easier way to do so, I will be happy to see it, because, currently I have a repeatable code for the .